# Quine-Putnam indispensability argument

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology, quine, hilary-putnam

If Quine-Putnam's argument is (following the [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathphil-indis/)):

- (P1) We ought to have ontological commitment to all and only the
  entities that are indispensable to our best scientific theories.
- (P2) Mathematical entities are indispensable to our best scientific
  theories.
- (C) We ought to have ontological commitment to mathematical
  entities.

I am reading this as a a *transfer* argument, where the supposed existence of the entities indispensable to our scientific theories is *transferred* to the mathematical objects used in those scientific theories.

Assuming this is tenable, is there a possible attack on premise (P1) along the lines that our best scientific theories do not necessarily involve any ontological commitment, so that no ontological commitment would be required of mathematics *even if* they were indispensable to our best scientific theories?

To restrict the discussion to physics, physics could be argued to propose only descriptive models that "work" more or less well in some range of parameters but do not necessarily carry a commitment to the existence of what they model. For example, "elementary particles" as point particles of matter are now superseded by "fields", just because the fields picture has more explanatory power. But if physicists needed to abandon the fields picture in favor of another model that would be a more accurate description, they would presumably do so, rather than cling to "particles" or "fields" just because they would have made some sort of "ontological commitment" through these models (it is actually more complicated, Newtonian gravity is useful in some range of parameters, while Einstein's SR and GR are useful in other ranges of parameters, there is a "classical limit" to QM, etc etc.)

So, if physics itself was seen to not actually make any kind of "ontological commitment" but instead be concerned with the descriptive power of models only, there would be no "ontological commitment" in physics to transfer to mathematics, *even if* mathematics were somehow deemed "indispensable" to physics.

As this kind of attack on (P1) been advanced by any philosopher?

Addendum: a variant on this attack could possibly be conceived by asking what happened to the ontological commitment to obsolete objects. If physics used some mathematical object X in theory A that was then superseded by theory B which no longer used mathematical object X, would the ontological commitment conferred to mathematical object X by its indispensability in physical theory A have to be retracted?

Comment: P1 is a formulation of scientific realism. For an anti-realist, there is no point engaging with the indispensability argument at all: if one does not believe that even physics describes reality (at least, partially, approximately and fallibly) why bother with mathematics. To those who do engage, the target is P2.

Comment: @Conifold So, that attack was not even levied at all, except to not even be considered by anti-realist philosophers? But even if one believes that physics partially, approximately and fallibly describes reality, is it possible for the description itself to not make any ontological commitment? Mathematics is entangled with the description, but the description may be changed as needed, possibly voiding previous ontological commitments? (see the addendum to the original question)

Comment: Ontological commitment is not some permanent attachment to a theory. It just means a realist accepts as existing those things that their best theories quantify over. If your best theories quantify over electrons then electrons exist. If your best theories quantify over numbers then numbers exist. If you exchange one theory for a better one, your ontological commitment changes with it.

Comment: @Bumble Isn't there a problem though in that if there is a series of different theories that posit different objects then ontological commitments to any particular object do not have any value? (because that commitment will have to change next time we posit another kind of object) How do we know we may eventually converge to the "true" objects?

Comment: @Bumble Doesn't that seem to empty "ontological commitment" of its actual meaning? Unless we are certain, those objects have no "existence" beyond what the models say, the models will change, and so... there is no "ontology" to be had?

Comment: When theories change there is continuity. To put it roughly, the old theory is a "homomorphic" image (typically, in some limit) of the new one. So we recommit to a refined version of the "same". I think what you are getting at with "description itself" is the representational aids objection. *Some* of indispensable mathematics just supplies descriptive aids and does not carry ontological commitments. Quine tried to address that by restricting commitments to domains of quantification (with the thought that pure aids are syntactic in nature), but that still turned out to be too broad.

Comment: @Conifold If we have to distinguish _which_ parts of maths are indispensable and which are just descriptive aids, it seems Quine's argument is considerably weakened. But what is a "domain of quantification" here? I've seen this idea of "quantification" (I'm assuming, "there exists") a few times here, but I'd like to see an example to ground the discussion.

Comment: It is not about parts, it is about uses. The same math, say geometry, can be used ontologically in one place (geodesy) and representationally in another (complex analysis). It can also be some complicated mixture, especially in secondary uses. I do not think it affects the argument much (that everything reduces to descriptive aids only is essentially physical anti-realism), but it does complicate the interpretation. How we distinguish ontological uses, and more pointedly, conceptualize their ontological input.

Comment: @Conifold Not sure "geometry" and "complex analysis" can be said to be the "same" maths (I know a fair bit of both). That would need to be made more precise.

Comment: I meant the standard [geometric representation of complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane). Domains are featured in the [Tarskian interpretations](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/#IntForPurQuaLog) of first order theories (the only ones Quine allows). They specify their semantic side as opposed to the syntactic side specified by symbols, formulas and formal rules/axioms.

Comment: My take on this is that P1 is so obviously a matter of belief & choice at best that it isn't even worth much bothering. Lots of philosphers won't buy into it (e.g., Bas van Fraassen, Karl Pearson, Wittgenstein, Thomas Kuhn, Nancy Cartwright,...), but it is somewhat harder to find straight on attacks, as people frankly deal with more interesting things (said of course somewhat polemically, but ultimately this is how I see it).

Comment: "[Has] this kind of attack on (P1) been advanced by any philosopher?" See Maddy & Sober's points in [Sec. 4](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathphil-indis/#Obje).

Comment: Different theories do indeed posit different objects and have differing ontologies. In fact, Quine is content to allow for Ontological Relativity (he has a paper of that name). We cannot be certain of a particular ontology, nor do we know we will converge to true objects. We are just sailing along in Neurath's boat progressing in the direction of better theories. It's the best we can do.

Comment: @Bumble So, we might as well dispense with "ontological commitments" and close this debate. I very much like the idea that since we are constantly changing the supposed "ontological commitment", there is no actual truth to that ontology...

Comment: Actual truth? Dispense with ontological commitment? 'Ontological commitment' means that people have beliefs that attribute existence to some things and not others, and draws the light to the pluralistic nature of what people accept as real. It cannot be dispensed with because it's an empirical fact that all people have different discriminators for the property 'real'. As for 'actual truth', it sounds like a phrase invoked on the eve of perpetrating a [no-true-Scotsman attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman). Truth itself is no brute fact.

Comment: @JD The fact is simply that if ontological commitments keep changing what's the point? Today, someone believe that X exists. Tomorrow, X no longer exists, but Y exists. The next day, both X and Y are possibly forgotten, in favor of Z that is now declared to "exist". Is it not apparent that if that's how it works, then we just don't know what really "exists"? It's always shifting and changing! Which is a real problem, because, actually, "reality" should _not_ change so easily. Why "commit" to something that constantly changes?

Comment: @Frank The point? Learning. When I was little, Santa existed. I learned otherwise. The same for God. Then centrigugal force. Then energy became nothing more than a fiction to account for the physical. As our notions of truth and reality evolve, so does our worldview. Our logic,  ontology, and epistemology must adapt to become more knowledgeable about ourselves and the world around us. What separates us from the stone age is nothing more than the sophistication of language. There may be no narrative to human existence, but there still is a moral obligation to be intelligent. ( Trelling.)

Comment: @JD Sure, then maybe we should just replace "ontological commitment" by "ontological fantasy of the day" in the philosophy books.

Comment: @Frank: Have you read and understood my answer? Don't be misled by the many philosophers who do not know enough logic to give any mathematically justified response.

Comment: @user21820 Sure - the debate about the "existence" of mathematical object is just boring and should be ejected from philosophy. It goes nowhere. It's not an important question. But I guess people love wasting time on it.

Comment: @Frank: I don't understand your response; it seems like you don't care about truth in contrast to your question. Also, you don't seem to have understood my answer, which clearly explains why the phrase "mathematical object" (which you used in your last comment) is meaningless.

Comment: @user21820 "Mathematical object" to a mathematician is something like a group, a vector space, a module, a function, or any number of other "objects" that they care to define. To ground the definition, you can use some "foundational system", and it's probably best to stay clear from the real world interpretation. Real world interpretations are just too limiting anyway, if you are a mathematician. Physicists are a different breed: they just use whatever works for their needs. Only philosophers who have nothing better to do wonder about the ontology of mathematical entities.

Comment: @Frank: Your comment does not seem to make sense. You ask for problems with this Quine-Putnam argument. The answer I had given adequately explains that the problem is not with (P1) but with (P2). Are you dismissing that because it's not the answer you want? As of today, physicists don't actually use anything that is stronger than ACA0, even if they claim they do. You seem to ignore this fact.

Comment: @user21820 I've just grown disillusioned with the whole question of the supposed ontology of mathematical entities.

Comment: I see, but that supports my answer even more, since my answer satisfactorily explains the indispensability of mathematics *without* requiring belief in ontology beyond the structure of ℕ! Unless you have a problem with ℕ, you are forced to accept that it *suffices* as ontological justification for our best scientific theories.

Comment: @user21820 Die ganzen Zahlen hat der liebe Gott gemacht, alles andere ist Menschenwerk.

Comment: That's kind of similar in spirit, yes... though I'm ambivalent about whether the 'true' real line is uncountable or not. Note that the standard intended model of ACA0 is countable, and the real line in this system is *also countable*, comprising only of reals computable from finite Turing jumps. This real line satisfies all the theorems that we associate with real analysis, including IVT, EVT, MVT and even an internal Dedekind-completeness axiom. So from inside it looks exactly like the standard (uncountable) ℝ, but it is countable and ontologically based on ℕ alone!

Answer (score 2):

These terms are broad brushes on articulate positions, but...

> if physics itself was seen to not actually make any kind of "ontological commitment" but instead be concerned with the descriptive power of models only

Ontological commitment as Quine entails it involves quantification over real things. Thus, for realists, physical theories are themselves committed to real entities. If one abandons that premise and instead moves away from realism to see physical theories are useful tools, fictions, or descriptions then one is engaged in an [instrumentalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentalism) (and therefore anti-realist) interpretation:

> In philosophy of science and in epistemology, instrumentalism is a methodological view that ideas are useful instruments, and that the worth of an idea is based on how effective it is in explaining and predicting phenomena. According to instrumentalists, a successful scientific theory **reveals nothing known either true or false about nature's unobservable objects, properties or processes**. Scientific theory is merely a tool whereby humans predict observations in a particular domain of nature by formulating laws, which state or summarize regularities, while theories themselves do not reveal supposedly hidden aspects of nature that somehow explain these laws. Instrumentalism is a perspective originally introduced by Pierre Duhem in 1906.[emphasis mine]

So, whereas the logical atomists presupposed that there was a straightforward [correspondent theory of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theory_of_truth) between propositional atoms and real things in the state of affairs in the world, an instrumentalist avoids that sort of commitment and might focus more instead on the coherence or the pragmatic grounding of truth.

As for the indispensability argument itself, [nominalism](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=nominalism) rejects such a thesis in the same way that [Wigner's  *The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Mathematics in the Natural Sciences*](https://The%20Unreasonable%20Effectiveness%20of%20Mathematics%20in%20the%20Natural%20Sciences) meets incredulity and charges of psychological bias that invokes the counter-accuastion of the [unreasonable ineffectiveness of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreasonable_ineffectiveness_of_mathematics). Hartry Field puts together one argument against indispensability, but there are broader attacks on the Platonic undercurrents of realism in mathematics such as those leveled by Brouwer and his [intuitionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism).

My believe is that philosophers of mathematics tend to asssert Platonic realism is powerfully intuitive, whereas those of us who are skeptical about such claims of facsimiles of a single [causally-linked time-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_closure) tend to view such a position as a [category mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake) confusing the mental for the physical. I like to refer people to Korzybski's pithy ["The map is not the territory."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation) Kant muddied the waters by claiming the physical as we understand it is a [phenomenalist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenomenalism) construct of the mind which is drawn from empirical doctrine, such that the perception is built from the senses. The contemporary linguist [Ray Jackendoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Jackendoff) argues that the causal chain is noises trigger language faculties which associate concepts that draw upon perceptions of objects, so things have gotten considerably more complicated since Kant drawing from the cognitive sciences such as psycholinguistics and neuroscience.

Last PhilPapers survey I read, IIRC, is about 80% of philosophers commit to being realist, and 20% not. The question of where to invoke the property 'real' is still quite a lively debate, and Duhem, Quine, and Putnam, as well as Dennett, Davidson, Churchland, and others are still being sorted out. Dennett in his book *Intentional Stance* and his later paper *Patterns* attempts to take a middle position between extreme realist and eliminative materialist notions of belief which seems to me to casting the property real itself as a belief. Amusingly at the end of the essay, he refuses to categorize himself leaving the reader with rhetorical questions instead.

Comment: So... if I sift through all this, would you say that instrumentalists may possibly have leveraged that kind of attack on Quine-Putnam's indispensability argument by claiming that physics in particular, makes no ontological commitment?

Comment: "My sense is that mathematicians tend to believe a word is a proof of thing" - my impression is that most mathematicians see mathematics as essentially abstract and not as "proof of thing". I have often seen mathematicians (and I am one by education & degree myself) bewildered by the in our view rather naive identification of mathematical results and physical truths that we find more in people who are non-mathematicians in the first place, even though maybe mathematically highly competent such as many physicists.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Morning! I'm eager for first-person reports. I read, ie, Linnebo and take his testimony as true prima facie on the dominance of Platonic thinking. Do you take a real number to be real in the sense it has an objective existence independent of people? Or like Brouwer, do you see it as a construction of the mind with no independent existence?

Comment: @JD I'm actually not much interested in "real existence". I think it's a red herring. I for sure see it as a construction of the mind, so I am with Brouwer at least half the way, however I don't think that this necessarily implies that "it doesn't really exist". I'm agnostic on that one, and I ultimately think there is no way to know this so why bother?

Comment: @ChristianHennig And you aver that this is a view typical of the average working mathematician, that your ontological agnosticism might not be a result of an above-average involvement in philosophical discourse?

Comment: @JD Well I didn't do empirical studies on it... however I've heard a number of other mathematicians commenting on these issues in a similar manner. Some even more antirealist ("atheist") than I am.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thanks! Of course, it's an empirical question, but reading philosophers of math, perhaps I've taken the claims of the dominance of realism applied to numbers and such things too naively, or have misconstrued, or there otherwise exists a bias in observation among philosophers of math who purport to speak for their colleagues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145530/discussion-between-j-d-and-christian-hennig).

Comment: @JD "Do you take a real number to be real in the sense it has an objective existence independent of people? Or like Brouwer, do you see it as a construction of the mind with no independent existence?" IMHO, asking that of most mathematicians will just leave them wanting to escape that conversation. Only philosophers care about the existence of mathematical objects ...

Comment: @JD The other thing is that "the existence of numbers" would barely scratch the surface of maths. How about complex numbers, matrices, groups, functions, vector spaces, algebras, topological spaces, separable and non-separable topological spaces, Hilbert spaces, differential equations, ... and the list of mathematical objects and theories goes on and on ... What do we do with all those other notions found in maths?

Comment: @Frank I'm not running for office, nor do I have an interest in specializing, which as Heinlein pointed out is for insects. Journals are rife with derivative papers and formal theories of no import. Today I learned that reverse mathematics is a domain from which to elicit truth, in a way incompleteness theorems and special relativity does. The various discipline in math are systems of abstractions each of which abstracts away different aspects of experience,  so they answer the more pressing issue of how the mind and brain function. Like Libet's task, they circumscribe the metaphysics...

Comment: @JD I'm glad Hilbert spaces abstract some aspect(s?) of your experience. One of these days, I'll be curious to hear more about that.

Comment: which speak to the nature of general intelligence that our neurology provides that the von Neumann architecture does not. Electronic computers are not even 100, and against the backdrop of 2,500 years of Western intelligentsia, it's only likely that a distributed architecture that uses symbolic and connectionist architectures will edge ever closer to the faculties we possess. In 20 more years when I have a better sense of what that it entails,  I may choose to take a stab at saying something memorable.

Comment: Of course it does the same way Euclidean spaces do,  but with a bit of real analysis applied to lines and curves. Without the abstraction of mathematical spaces,  there would be no autopilots or self- driving cars! We certainly haven't achieved the last transportation possible. Why wouldn't be curious as to what future technologies bring?!? I suspect FTL isn't only science fiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145544/discussion-between-j-d-and-frank).

Answer (score 2):

This popular 'indispensability argument' is completely fallacious. For instance, it claims that "reference to (or quantification over) mathematical entities such as sets, numbers, functions and such is indispensable to our best scientific theories". This is plainly false. It is [well-known to all real experts in logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) that very weak subsystems of second-order arithmetic suffice for all empirically backed real-world applications of mathematics to date.

In particular, our best scientific theories only rely on mathematics that can be carried out in such weak systems, apparently not needing reasoning about anything beyond arithmetical sets, and this can be handled easily by ACA0 or at most ACA (i.e. ACA0 plus full induction). So the popular notion that set theory is indispensable to science is just bogus.

More specifically, "mathematical entities" is ill-defined until you specify a foundational system and provide some kind of real-world or ontological interpretation, which Putnam utterly failed to do. In fact, ACA can be interpreted to have nothing to do with sets at all. On the surface, ACA is about ℕ and its arithmetical subsets. However, that is mere appearance. We could use the obvious interpretation of ℕ in terms of finite binary encodings in some specific physical medium with the appropriate operations on them, and we could interpret those 'subsets' as simply arithmetical formulae with one free variable. For any such set S = { x : x∈ℕ ∧ Q(x) }, the truth-value of "k∈S" for k∈ℕ is simply the truth-value of "Q(k)", which is already well-defined once you believe the meaningfulness of PA.

Therefore even if we accept (P1), if you think carefully you will see that (P2) is utterly meaningless. What is defensible is:

(P3) We can **reasonably** have ontological commitment to existence of a **model of a foundational system** whose **theorems** are indispensable to our best scientific theories.

(P4) The theorems of ACA0 are indispensable to our best scientific theories.

Conclusion: We can reasonably have ontological commitment to the existence of a model of ACA0. No problem. Almost all real logicians believe this.

Comment: The argument uses "mathematical entities" so as to leave open which foundational system is at play. So its seems a bit heavy handed to criticize Putnam for "failing" to specify a foundational system.  Quine himself uses the argument to justify transfinite set theory, yes, but contemporary defenders of the argument need not commit themselves to this ( as you yourself note)

Comment: @Papuseme: I read this answer as a form of [nominalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nominalism-mathematics/), in which it is argued that we only need to bother dealing with very simple mathematical objects (the natural numbers), and can therefore sidestep many of the traditional objections to nominalism. In that interpretation, the idea is not necessarily that Putnam is wrong, but rather that Putnam is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

P1, P2 and C are all open to challenge. Take the electron. The term is really shorthand for 'that which causes certain types of detectable effects'. We can be committed to the existence of the effects, and we can be committed to their seeming to have a common cause, but the history of science is littered with ideas such as phlogiston, the ether, fluxions and so on that would once have been considered indispensable to the then best theories. It might be that in n years the idea of an electron will join all the other outdated terms. When you say that mathematical entities are indispensable, one might argue that they are just stand-ins representing the attributes of the 'real' entities, so they do not count as objects which demand an ontological commitment in themselves. So, the argument can be paraphrased another way:

Our theories assume the existence of entities whose fundamental nature is questionable.

We use mathematical symbols to represent the apparent properties of those entities.

Ergo we should be committed to the existence of mathematical objects.

I struggle to think of a less appropriate use of the word 'ergo'.

Answer (score 1):

For Quine, and as linked in your article, ontological commitment is as follows:
"to be is to be the value of a bound variable"

Since formalizations of physics typically involve quantification over mathematical objects, the Quinean is commited to all and only yhese entities which are quantified over. For a  physics without numbers, see Fields.

So yes , a different notion of ontological commitent might not fare as well for Quibes argument. Lowe has a lucid discussion on various notions of ontological commitment if you are interested.

As for your example, the question is whether the new theories ultimately quanitfy over mathematical entities. If they do, the quniean will be unconvinced that they do not carry ontological commitment.

Comment: What does it mean to "quantify over mathematical objects"?

Comment: The proposed line of attack though, is that there may well be no ontological commitment, of any kind, in the case of physics, but only descriptive models.

Comment: 1) to quantify over them in some logic or model thereof 2) does your descriptive model quantify over mathematical entities? if so, the quniean beleives you have made an onotlogical commitment. Else, youre going the way of Field- nomiinzalization.

Comment: @Frank This is [existential quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) and is used in the logical sense of binding a variable to a domain logically.

Comment: @JD Still fuzzy, does this mean, for example "there exists a function in a Hilbert space that represents a particle"? What would be examples of "variables" and "domain" here?

Comment: Frank, please see IEP on indispensabikity for an example of quantification over sets in the formulkation of coulombs law. As for your comment, if you say there exists a linear function from a Hilbert space to itself, you are commiting to the existence of the Hilbert space, as well as functijons. So your domain must contain at least those. Your variables are ranging over at least sets (presumably if you take ZF as your foundation)

Comment: @Frank The skinny is that any natural language formulation "There exists X such that X might by one or more of the set Y" encapsulates quantification. Quine takes such quantification as a determinant of existence. Hilbert spaces commit to points, measurable distances, and directions, so algebraic claims such as ∃x, x∈R are interpreted as claims of ontological reality with the same vigor as "Electrons exist". ∃x, x∈R. X is the variable which is bound to a real value, which is the set that is a domain. In physics ∃e-, e-∈sub-atomic particles is seen by logics as an equivalent sort of claim.

Comment: @JD Great. So now, instead of saying "I see a tree in my garden", I can say "I see something quantified over the set of plant objects" and sound smart. What has been gained? Besides being a pedantic way of saying "there is", is that "quantification" actually used to carry out some formal logical reasoning?

Comment: @Frank What is gained (according to Quine, and not me), that the use of such philosophical language generalizes existence to conclude metaphysically that numbers exist. I personally don't buy it, so I'd be a lackluster defender of the premise. You certainly don't have to like Quine or his methods or his conclusions. But you won't be competent to rebut such arguments if you aren't at least fluent in discussing them. :D

Comment: @JD My gripe was only about the language "quantify over mathematical objects", which doesn't seem to be specially productive - unless Quine actually writes down quantifiers and starts doing some formal logic. Otherwise, he could as well have said "there exists" in plain English - unless I'm missing something, of course.

Comment: @Frank lol I would say your objection to the phrase is it's hyperproduced, and that you're missing the fact that Quine was logician by training and trade. Expecting ducks not to quack is a high-bar, indeed. That being said, I appreciate your appreciation of parsimony. ; )

Comment: @Frank that quantification is indeed used to carry out formal reasoning, Quine does not use plain english because his proejct was a regimented natural language. But the upshot is the same- if our best theories (in a regimented language) say that electrons and sets exist, the quinean believes it is incongruent to then only claim that only one of them "actually" exists

Comment: @Papuseme No problem, I understand what Quine is getting at. I'm only complaining that he uses seemingly pedantic language.